# Which month has the highest cumulative sum in multiindex pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, multi-index

I have this `MultiIndex` pandas dataframe:

```
            chamber_temp
month day          
1     1    0.000000
      2    0.005977
      3    0.001439
      4   -0.000119
      5    0.000514
            ...
12    27   0.001799
      28   0.002346
      29  -0.001815
      30   0.001102
      31  -0.004189
```

What I want to get is which month has the highest cumsum().
What I am trying to do is for each month there should 1 value which will give me the cumulative sum of all the values for `day` in that month, that is the problem which I am trying to get help on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Try

```
df.groupby('month')['chamber_temp'].sum().idxmax()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can leverage on `level` parameter in [`Series.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sum.html) when there's `MultiIndex` to avoid `groupby` in such cases.

```
df['champer_temp'].sum(level=0).idxmax()
```